# tablesorter with scroller widget not sorting fixed columns

Tags: jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I'm trying to set up freeze pane (sticky header and fixed columns) using the scroller widget. When I add it to my table the sorting "breaks" in the following way: clicking on one of the fixed columns headers (first or last name in my table), sorts by one of the non fixed columns.

Any ideas?

Thanks

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgec57nt/3/)

```
$('#spreadsheet_table').tablesorter({
                         widgets: [ 'scroller' ],
                         widgetOptions : {
                             scroller_fixedColumns : 2,
                             scroller_addFixedOverlay : true,
                             scroller_rowHighlight : 'hover',
                             scroller_barWidth : null
                         }
                    });
                    $('#spreadsheet_table').tablesorter();
                    $('#spreadsheet_table').trigger('update');
                    var sorting = [[1, 0]];
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#spreadsheet_table').trigger('sorton', [sorting]);
                    }, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`sortList` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sortlist) as an initialization option instead of trying to trigger a sort after tablesorter has initialized - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgec57nt/5/)

```
$('#spreadsheet_table').tablesorter({
  theme: 'blue',
  sortList: [[1, 0]],
  widgets: ['scroller'],
  widgetOptions: {
    scroller_fixedColumns: 2,
    scroller_addFixedOverlay: true,
    scroller_rowHighlight: 'hover',
    scroller_barWidth: null
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks @Mottie. on my smal example it's working great. but my big table contains 3 rows in <tbody>. the first 2 rows are not sortable and the last row on <thead> is sortable. when i click on the third row it's not working,BUT clicking on the first row does sort.